# Convert data object's data to string type

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have made a REST API call. In which I am getting the content of a .doc file. But the data is coming in some unknown format. How I can convert this data to simple string.

```
$.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Template Documents/Report.docx')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {

                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.toString());
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
     });
```

I am getting this in `data`:[image]
Even I tried to convert it into a string with `toString()`, but still didn't get any luck. Please help.

Comment: What's unknown about the format? You're requesting a `docx` file, seems like you're getting a `docx` file. What did you expect?

Comment: A word document is binary data...logging it won't produce anything meaningful

Comment: I want the actual content of the file in readable format.

Comment: Then you need a library to convert docx file...if you can even find one. Browsers can't read all file extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
window.location.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

if you want to show the file to the user.